# How to search different type at elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few type at index, like _type: HKN, _type:hke,_type: uun

```
"_index": "news",
"_type": "hkn"
```

if only one type I know as below:

```
POST /news/hkn/_search{}
```

if all type will be:

```
POST /news/_search{}
```

How about I want selected few type like "HKN and UUN"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To search multiple types, separate them with a comma:

```
POST /news/hkn,uun/_search{}
```